# Exporting feature class in one shapefile to new shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, feature-class, copy

In ArcMap, how can you export the feature class of one shapefile to a new shapefile?

I want everything in the old shapefile to go into the new shapefile.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the shapefile in the table of contents. Select Export Data. Choose Export all features and select the coordinate system you want. You can either keep the projection of the current shapefile or re-project if the dataframe has a different projection. Pro tip...if you have a shapefile that doesn't match the projection of all your other shapefiles within the mxd, you can use this method to change the shapefile's projection.

[image: Snapshot from ArcMap]

Answer (score 1):

You use the [Copy Features](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm) tool which:

> Copies features from the input feature class or layer to a new feature
>   class. If the input is a layer which has a selection, only the
>   selected features will be copied. If the input is a geodatabase
>   feature class or shapefile, all features will be copied.